# How to send data over SSH connection created by AWS SSM Session Manager without using plugin?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I want to send data over the SSH connection created by AWS SSM Session Manager in Python without using the **Session Manager Plugin**.

The following answer describes how to do it using the plugin, but I want a pure Python approach, with a local port that's forwarded to a target host.

Any ideas?

[How to use session-manager-plugin command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222667/how-to-use-session-manager-plugin-command/70311671#70311671)

Comment: `scp` is not an option?

Comment: No, I would like to establish an interactive SSH session :)